# Definition of finite-by-nilpotent

Tags: group-theory, definition

In group theory what are definitions of:

1. finite-by-nilpotent,
2. nilpotent-by-finite,
3. abelian-by-finite,
4. or in general: *-by- *?

Comment: In what context have you encountered these expressions?

Comment: @MarkBennet on a paper about finite conjugacy groups.

Comment: I really cannot imagine why this question was closed! What are the "many possible answers"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A group $G$ is called X-by-Y if it has a normal subgroup $N$ that belongs to the class X and the quotient $G/N$ belongs to the class Y.

Comment: But unfortunately many authors use the opposite convention, i.e. a normal subgroup $N$ in $Y$ with $G/N$ in $X$. This means that when anyone you don't know refers for example to a nilpotent-by-abelian group, then you have to ask them which convention they are using, because it really could be either.